# Login validation

Tags: iphone

I need to do a login validation where in the username and password could be checked from a set of values which is stored in an array ....... 
I also want help in how to get to a new XIB on clicking the login button that is how to get to a new view . 
Going through some documents i found that "initinitWithNibName " could be used but its not given how to use.

Please help .....

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to split your question in two questions.

Comment: We can't learn iPhone development for you, you have to do it yourself. Start small and work your way up. Ask questions when you have more specific problems.

Comment: Oh, and initWithNibName *is* well documented. You have to find the information. Apple's website, google, etc.

Answer (score 0):

for your second question means to load from nib on click of login button perform this:

```
ClassViewController *viewController = [[ClassViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ClassViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
```

And as @xCode says you should use most of your time on iOS fundamentals. Enjoy iPhone programming.

Comment: A UIViewController's view should be presented carefully -- by which I mean, not just adding as a subview. Pushing it modally, or onto a nav controller or similar, is the usual way.